# FFMPEG loses drop frame flag when converting from 29.97 mov to mp4

Tags: ffmpeg

I've got a 29.97 drop frame video, proven with the mediainfo output lines `framerate: 29.97` and `Delay_DropFrame: Yes`. I want to convert it to an mp4.

Running `ffmpeg -i INPUT.mov -y -b:v 1500k -vcodec libx264 -vf scale=640:-1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart -strict -2 OUTPUT.mp4`
yields a non-drop frame video. When I run mediainfo against the new file, I can see that the framerate is still 29.97, but there is no indication of drop frame anymore.
This also happens when i run the above outputting an mov, and also when i run `ffmpeg -i INPUT.mov OUTPUT.mov`, so i think it's purely in the conversion where the data is being lost.

One lead i'm following is that mediainfo outputs 3 sections for the original mov, [General], [Video], [Other], while my new mp4 only outputs [General] and [Video].

My FFMPEG version is 3.4.1
Any ideas?

Comment: ffmpeg version?

Comment: @Gyan 3.4.1. Updated the question as well